# How do I get the raw request I am sending out in node

Tags: node.js

I am using the request library to send a request and it works great! However, when I try to make what seems to be the same request in postman it fails. I would like to see the raw request node is sending out but I can't find how to do that in the docs. How do I view a raw request when using node and the request modue?

Comment: Can just use a proxy, too. Could probably build that into your existing app.

Comment: That was kinda what I was looking for help with I saw mitm module but my company limits external modules so I would like a more native pattern.

Comment: A simple proxy is dozens of lines of code at the most. Not to mention you could just copy the relevant bits of code out of GH.